# How can I find duplicates in a column, using formulas?

Tags: google-sheets

Has anybody come up with a formula to find duplicates in a column? For example:

```
a
b
c
d
b
d
```

`=somefunction(A1:A6)`

Output:

```
b
d
```

I know there is a `=unique()` function, it's basically a `=not_unique()` function. Was wondering if it can be constructed without using code.

Comment: Here is one example in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19843406/mark-duplicate-entries-in-google-spreadsheet have a look at this which could get you with some idea.

Comment: Wait, what you're looking for is a `not_unique` function right? You seem to be looking for the fields that are not unique (the duplicates), not the fields that *are* unique.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The possible solution without an additional column is:

```
=FILTER(UNIQUE(A2:A7), ARRAYFORMULA( COUNTIF(A2:A7,UNIQUE(A2:A7))>1 ))
```

Please, see prepared example here: **[Find Duplicates](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gktHBKdbt66k3sZgAJJzFE7a6aG24lsgu6aFXjeWWLs/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 4):

The only way I found (using formulas) is by introducing a new `count` column.

If your values are listed in column `A`, starting on row `2`, enter the formula `=COUNTA(FILTER(A$2:A$7, A$2:A$7 = A2))` in `B2` and drag down to copy it. This gives:

```
| A: VALUE  | B: COUNT |
|-----------|----------|
|     a     |     1    |
|     b     |     2    |
|     c     |     1    |
|     d     |     2    |
|     b     |     2    |
|     d     |     2    |
```

Now that we have a count of occurences of each value, we can filter the `A` column by values from `B`. In cell `C2`, insert the formula `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A7, B2:B7 > 1))`. This gives:

```
| A: VALUE  | B: COUNT | C: DUPS |
|-----------|----------|---------|
|     a     |     1    |    b    |
|     b     |     2    |    d    |
|     c     |     1    |         |
|     d     |     2    |         |
|     b     |     2    |         |
|     d     |     2    |         |
```

## Explanation of formulas

### `=COUNTA(FILTER(A$2:A$7, A$2:A$7 = A2))`

- The `filter` clause inspects the `A` column, and finds cells which have the same value as cell `A2` (`A2` is replaced with the corresponding cell when copying the formula).
- `counta` counts values (including non-numeric).

### `=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A7, B2:B7 > 1))`

- This `filter` examines column `B` for values that are `> 1`, and returns the corresponding values from column `A`. The `unique` function simply makes sure we only return each value once, so we don´t get `b` twice, for example.

---

**However**, a more elegant way would be to use a script function:

```
function dups(rows) {
  var values = {};
  var duplicates = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var value = rows[i][0];
    if (values[value] !== undefined && duplicates.indexOf(value) == -1) {
      duplicates.push(value);
    } else {
      values[value] = true
    }
  }
  return duplicates;
}
```

Go to *Tools → Script Editor*, paste the above code, and save. You can now call the function by entering the formula `=dups(A2:A7)` anywhere. This returns the duplicates found in `A2:A7`.

---

I have set up [an example spreadsheet to demonstrate both possibilites](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KfNUEwsgh4Om0WS_os5QGUfBzj2K3R42Qbxh8JrNur0/edit?usp=sharing), feel free to look at it and copy it.

Comment: _var values = {}_ needs to be _var values = []_ right?

Comment: Actually, no. `values` is used as a key-value map, not an array, so that it is easy to check if we have processed a specific value already - either the `values[property]` exists, or it doesn't.

Comment: I thought you were pushing into an array.... I tested your code and it keeps showing duplicate entries, as in _d,d,d,d..._. The formula solution you provided doesn't do that.

Comment: I meant object.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Ah, yes - I see that now. Corrected the code.