# Can I check that all cells in a column contain unique values?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm have a list of IDs in a column on Google Spreadsheets. I need to check:

1. That there are no duplicates in the column
2. Which cells contain the duplicates

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 10):

A closely related question is [How can I find duplicates in a column, using formulas?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/82278/how-can-i-find-duplicates-in-a-column-using-formulas) but your desired output is somewhat different (you want to see the *cells* that contain duplicates rather than just the values themselves).

1. The formula `=counta(A1:A)-countunique(A1:A)` evaluates to zero if all entries in A are unique; otherwise it shows how many duplicates are there.
2. To see which cells contain duplicate IDs, apply conditional formatting to column A1:A with the custom formula `=countif(A$1:A, A1)>1`   (If the range was instead B3:B, the formula would be `=countif(B$3:B, B3)>1`).

Comment: Thanks! `=if(counta($B$3:$B$1000)-COUNTUNIQUE($B$3:$B$1000)>0,"ERROR","no dupes")` was what I needed.